# Keyboard shortcuts involving Shift and digits

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to set `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+1` to Move a window to workspace 1.

Settings->Keyboard->Navigation->Move window to workspace 1

When I type the new accelerator, what shows up is `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+!`. `!` is of course `Shift+1`.

Two issues:

1. The keyboard shortcut does not work.
2. If it did I am afraid that it would break when I use different keyboard layouts (`Shift+4` is not the same character in both layouts I use).

How do I fix the `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+1` shortcut?

---

Edit:

It turns out that  "Put On Viewport #" in CCSM Plugin "Put" kind of works. `<Control><Shift><Alt>exclam` is the string generated for `1`, but it works even if the layout does not have `!` on `Shift+1`.

Still an issue with that: the action puts the window in an arbitrary viewport, but then *switches to that viewport*. That is not what I want.

Comment: As you have compact keyboard why not just use `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+!` (that's stored in system, for you it's just `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+1`)

Comment: Compact keyboard? I would be ok with it if the shortcut `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+!` was working. As stated in my question, it does not work. Furthermore, `Shift+4` in `$` in US layout, `¤` in swedish layout. I use both.

Answer (score 1):

In 14.04:

- Install and start CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM).
- Activate the plugin "Put" in Window Managemnet, and edit its settings as follows.
- Setup your shortcuts in "Put to arbitrary viewport -> Put On Viewport #". Keep the `exclam`, `at`, ... This will work even if these are not the correct characters for your current keyboard layout.
- If you don't want the view to follow the window you just put on another viewport, go to the tab "Misc. Options" and select "Unfocus Window".

This does not explain why the shortcuts in the regular Unity Keyboard settings do not work, but it is a workaround that I am happy with.

Comment: In 14.04.1, I don't have Put anymore :(